Identifying the necessary permissions of a user in linux
There is a linux user, lets call it config, with same UID as root i.e. 0. This user was used by several process to update the device and many more system level things. This seems to be an issue and I need to change the uid of config to something other than 0 (i.e. root). Once I do that I see the several process crash due to file permission issues and sometimes the device enters an unrecoverable state.
I would like to know is there a way I can change the UID of config user and put the device in some mode (permissive in case of selinux) to identify all the file permission violations and update those file permissions in one shot.
If that is not a viable way, is there any better way to approach this problem?
I tried moving the config user to root group and changing the UID, however still I see file permission issues.

Why does having config with uid 0 "seem to be an issue"?

Does the system currently have SELinux active?

@choroba "A user identifier (UID) is a unique numerical value that identifies a user account in Linux." from the defination it does not seem to be a good practice to have multiple user with same uid. Also I want to trim the reuired privelages for the config user to necessary rather than blindly giving root permission.

@grawity_u1686 No it does not have selinux

Side note (paradigm shift): it's not "multiple users with same uid", it's "one user with multiple names".

@KamilMaciorowski That sound more appropriate

Do the answers here answer your question https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/466688/247007 ? You can delete the 'config' user and create a new one with a different uid, but it's worth checking whether any processes are running as that user with ps -ef|grep config for example

@Cpt.Whale
ps -ef would just the process launched by config user once I change th uid of config this process crashes due to file permission issue, earlier config being root user had all the permission but now it does't. I would like to list all the file permission violation without crashing the process, instead of going through each process and trying to understand what file access they need.

Would AppArmor be available on the system? I very faintly remember it having some way to audit "capability use" (e.g. when a process relies on cap_dac_override to bypass permissions)... but even if it doesn't have that, an empty AppArmor profile in complain mode would be my next try

it does not have AppArmor its a small device with limited resources
